# Duplicated usage of stdin in bash

Tags: bash, awk, stdin

I want to give awk two input files which both contain the contents of stdin. When I tried doing so weird things happened. So I simulated the experiment by echoing some input on stdin and things don't work as expected either.

```
echo 88 | awk '1' - -
```

gives 88

```
 echo 88 | tee outfile | awk '1' - -
```

still gives 88.

```
echo 88 | tee outfile | awk '1' - outfile
```

correctly prints 88 twice

However the tee should be unnecessary shouldn't it?

Comment: Why not`echo 88 | awk '{print $0,$0}'` simple one?

Comment: Looking for an explanation why the first example doesn't work. It is supposed to be giving awk two rows of input but only one is output.

Comment: The dash (`-`) means that the `stdin` stream is consumed, so when you access it the second time, there'll be nothing in it. Or would you hope not to get all of `stdin` when you read it?

Comment: Note that replacing - with /dev/stdin still doesn't work. Is that what you would expect also?

Comment: You cannot drink from the same river twice.

Answer (score 0):

Standard input is a stream; what you consume is forever removed from it. What you can do is save standard input to a temporary file, then remove it when you are done.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Nothing here is Bash-specific
# Create a temporary file; fail if it can't be done
t=$(mktemp -t savestdin.XXXXXXXXX) || exit
# Set up an exit trap to remove the temporary file
trap 'rm -f "$t"' EXIT
trap 'exit 126' HUP INT TERM
# Save input
cat >"$t"
# Your stuff here
awk '1' "$t" "$t"
```

Comment: I think that's what I did with tee in the last example.

Comment: Pretty much, except you litter the system with a temp file which you fail to remove,

Comment: Yes it's meant to be an illustrative example not real code.